# Manipulating dataframes, flagging errors and returning new dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, duplicates, flags

I have a dataset where 2 recorders (Jack and Jane) logged race times for 5 runners (each runner has a unique id number). I am trying to identify discrepancies in the race times logged by the two recorders and return a new dataset with the flagged rows and boolean True/False in the column containing the error.

mydata:

```
runner_id  recorder  run_time_one  run_time_two  run_time_three
        1   jack      2             2              1
        1   jane      2             2              1
        2   jack      1             3              2  
        2   jane      2             3              2
        3   jack      3             2              1
        3   jane      3             1              1 
        4   jack      2             3              3
        4   jane      2             3              2
        5   jack      2             1              1
        5   jane      2             1              1
```

I need to return a new dataset like this:

```
runner_id  run_time_one  run_time_two  run_time_three
        2     False           True             True
        3     True            False            True
        4     True            True             False
```

runner 2 should be flagged for the error in column `run_time_one`
runner 3 should be flagged for the error in column `run_time_two`
runner 4 should be flagged for the error in column `run_time_three`

Answer (score 0):

If your data has the property that every runner is observed once by each recorder and your data frame is sorted by runner_id (both of which are true in your example), then here's a possible `base` R approach:

```
df <- data.frame(
  runner_id = rep(1:5, each = 2),
  recorder = rep(c("jack", "jane"), times = 5),
  run_time_one = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  run_time_two = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1),
  run_time_three = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1)
) # recreate the data set

flags <- df[df$recorder == "jack", 3:5] != df[df$recorder == "jane", 3:5]
  # create data frame with binary indicator of disagreement between recorders
flags <- data.frame(runner_id = df[df$recorder == "jack", ]$runner_id, flags)
  # glue runner id back onto flags column
flags[rowSums(flags[2:4, ]) > 0, ]
  # display subset of data frame with any disagreements
```

If it might be the case that Jake and Jane observed differing sets of runners (e.g. Jack was the only observer for runner 6), then please feel free to let me know that along with how would you like that situation resolved in the output.